# Custom post type sorting: alphabetical order

Tags: custom-post-types, order, sort

I want to display my custom post type "portfolio" in alphabetical order and I got it working fine with this code:

```
add_filter("posts_orderby", "my_orderby_filter", 10, 2);

function my_orderby_filter($orderby, &$query){
    global $wpdb;
    //figure out whether you want to change the order
    if (get_query_var("post_type") == "portfolio") {
         return "$wpdb->posts.post_title ASC";
    }
    return $orderby;
    }
```

Unfortunately it affects also normal posts order list. I don't know why.
How may I fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$query->get()` instead of `get_query_var()`.

```
function my_orderby_filter($orderby, &$query){
    global $wpdb;
    //figure out whether you want to change the order
    if ($query->get("post_type") == "portfolio") {
         return "$wpdb->posts.post_title ASC";
    }
    return $orderby;
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use this one, which filters the query via the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) hook.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_orderby_filter2' );
function my_orderby_filter2( $query ) {
    if ( 'portfolio' === $query->get( 'post_type' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. To do this for several post types, I used $post_types = array( 'different', 'post', 'types' ); then if( in_array( $query->get('post_type'), $post_types ) for my conditional.